# PerlTk with MacTex BasicTeX

Tags: mactex, tlmgr, perl

I have the BasicTex version of MacTeX installed on my machine. I would like to use the gui for tlmgr, but when I try to run it, I'm informed I need perl/tk. After some Internet searching it seems like its a bad idea to mess with the system perl by installing this module. Should I install a separate version of perl? How would I then configure that with my TeX distribution?

Comment: @AlanMunn BasicTex does not install Tex Live Utility. From the website: ["BasicTeX only contains the TeX Live piece of the full distribution; it does not contain GUI programs or Ghostscript"](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html)

Comment: So then download TeX Live Utility here: https://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't want to.